# SQL Queries to select from two tables and compare with third

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am new to sql and trying to execute a query.

I have created the following tables and they work properly.

```
create table ACTOR
(
   actor_name varchar(30),
   gender varchar(8),
   date_of_birth date,
   primary key(actor_name)
);
```

I keep getting stuck at on how to compare with the the cast_memeber table.

```
 select movie_title as MOVIE_TITLE
```

Comment: How to Compare, You mean a `JOIN` with `CAST_MEMBER` ?

Comment: this is what i have tried so far
SQL> select movie_title as MOVIE_TITLE, release_year as RELEASE_YEAR, actor.actor_name, actor.gender from MOVIE movie , ACTOR actor
  2  where actor.actor_name = CAST_MEMEBER.actor_name;

Comment: We use table and column aliases to **change the name** we use to reference the object.  There's no point in aliasing `movie_title as MOVIE_TITLE`, unless you feel you need the typing practice.

Comment: @APC , I wanted to display it that way so used 'as' operator.

Comment: MOVIE_TITLE will display as `MOVIE_TITLE`.  That's the default behaviour.  We only need to use an alias if we want something different from the column name in upper case.  Same with the table aliases.

Comment: Add this to your query `count(actor 2.actor_name)` before where clause and add `actor 2.actor_name=CAST_MEMBER.actor.name and CAST_MEMBER.movie_title=movie.movie_title and actor 2.gender=female` after where clause it should work.

Comment: @APC will keep a note of that. thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For conditional count you can use `SUM()` with your expression,join your `CAST_MEMEBER` and `ACTOR` table use `COUNT()` to count all members for a movie and sum with expression will result as a boolean so doing this will give you the count based on your conditions

```
SELECT 
  m.movie_title,
  m.release_year,
  SUM(a.gender = 'female') no_of_female_members,
  SUM(a.gender = 'male') no_of_male_members,
  COUNT(c.actor_name) no_of_all_members 
FROM
  MOVIE m 
  LEFT JOIN CAST_MEMEBER c 
    ON (m.movie_title = c.movie_title AND m.release_year = c.release_year) 
  JOIN ACTOR a 
    ON (a.actor_name = c.actor_name) 
GROUP BY m.movie_title,m.release_year
```

Comment: @M_Khalid, thank you for the response but just a follow up question,
no_of_female_members, <--- does this act as a variable that stores all the number of females? just a little confused on that. 

thank you

Comment: @Mani its a alias to the result of `SUM(a.gender = 'female')` its not a variable just a temporary column for the current query

Answer (score 1):

```
select movie_title,
       release_year,
       count(decode(t.gender,'FEMALE',1)) female_actors
from movie m , (select c.movie_title 
                       a.gender,
                       c.release_year
                from cast_member c, actor a
                where c.movie_title = a.movie_title
                  and c.actor_name = a.actor_name) t
where m.movie_title  = t.movie_title
  and m.release_year = t.release_year
group by m.movie_title ,t.release_year
```